# In Python, how to make a type hint for a N dimensional list without fixing N?

Tags: python

I've seen numpy is able to annotate multidimensional arrays, but you have to define the number of dimensions first.

I need to make a type that will fit for both [1, 2] and [[1, 2], [3, 4]] at the same time. Something like:

`list[T | list[T] | list[list[T]] | ...]`

Context: I'm trying to implement a function to flatten arrays with unknown dimensions, with proper type hints.

Comment: The documentation on [`typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) states: "*To specify a variable-length tuple of homogeneous type, use literal ellipsis, e.g. Tuple[int, ...]*" Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke doesn't look like it. A tuple of variable-length is similar to a regular list, right? It's a single dimension collection with variable number of elements (unlike regular tuples that have a fixed length). What I'm looking for though is a multidimensional collection, and even more so, one with unknown number of dimensions (so its accepted values could be a normal list, or a list of lists, or a list of lists of lists...)